# Filter WooCommerce products by taxonomy terms and custom fields in a WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, taxonomy-terms

In WooCommerce, I have a product category `boots-2` *(term slug)* with 350 products in it.

I need to return all products that are in this category that have the meta key `_translate_lock` with a meta value **`1`** as defined in the WP_Query below:

Here is my code

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '400',
        'category' => 'boots-2',
        'post_type'  => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
            'key' => '_translate_lock',
                'value' => '1',
            'compare' => '='
            )
        ),
    );

    $query  = new  WP_Query($args);


    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

            $query->the_post();

            $productId = get_the_ID() ;
            println("retrieved product id is $productId");
            
        }
    } 
    wp_reset_query();
```

This code returns products that don't belong the the category with the category slug `boots-2`, i've tried changing the query string to `cat=881` where 881 is the `tag_id` of the category but the code still returns products from other categories.

What am I missing ?

Comment: You are using `key` twice in the `meta_query` array... possibly not the reason for this problem, but worth looking into anyway :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten sure, that was a typo,, i am correcting the question.

Answer (score 1):

First Woocommerce product category is a custom taxonomy that has nothing to do with WordPress category. Now for a [WP_Query and taxonomy parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) is better to use a tax query like:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'orderby'        => 'name',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'     => array(
        array(
            'key'       => '_translate_lock',
            'value'     => '1',
            // 'compare'    => '=' // not needed as default value is '='
        )
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat', // Woocommerce product category taxonomy
            'field'     => 'slug', // can be: 'name', 'slug' or 'term_id'
            'terms'     => array('boots-2'),
        )
    ),
) );

$results = []; // Initializing

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $product_id   = get_the_ID();
        $product_name = get_the_title();

        $results[] = $product_name .' ('.$product_id.')'; 
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Displaying results
    printf( '<p><strong>Retrieved products are</strong>:<br> %s<p>', implode(',<br>', $results) ); 
else :
    echo '<p>No results found.</p>';
endif;
wp_reset_query();
```

Tested and works.

See [WP_Query - taxonomy-parameters section documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters)